# jqm thumbs list not displaying correctly

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I have two lists in a dialog - one bubble count list and one thumbs list. The bubble count list looks fine, but the thumbs list is displayed as separate list items.

[image]

I'm not used to writing the html output this way, maybe I'm missing something simple. The code for the bubble count list is below "//assign movie folder to child" and the code for the thumbs list is below "//display image count, encode url path":

```
private function _makeoutput($folder_index) {

$html = '';

    $query = 'dir§'.$this->session->userdata('uid').'§'.$folder_index;

    //api query, create listview for images
    if($xml = $this->api->query($query)){
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" text-align:center;>';

    //assign movie folders to child
    foreach($xml->COM->MOVIE_FOLDER as $child){
       $html .= '<li>';
       //count number of images in each root folder
       $bubble_count = $child->MOVIE->count();
       $html .= '<a href="'.$child->attributes()->indexI.'" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slide">'.$child->attributes()->nameS.'<span class="ui-li-count">'.$bubble_count.'</span></a>';
       $html .= ' </li>';
    }
    $html .= '</ul>';

    //display image count, encode url/path
    for($i = 0, $c = $xml->COM->MOVIE->count(); $i < $c; $i++ ){
        $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview" data-inset="true">';
        $html .= '<li>';
        $html .= '<a>
        <img src="https://[url]'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" id="imgThumb" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'" />
        <h1>'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'</h1>
        </a>';
        $html .= ' </li>';
        $html .= '</ul>';
    }
    }
    else{
    $data['output'] = $this->_makeoutput($folder_index);
    }
return $html;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first off.. Why 'private'?

the issue at hand is you need the ul tag outside of the for loop else you generate new lists (and that's what you're seeing):

```
$html .= '<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview" data-inset="true">';
for($i = 0, $c = $xml->COM->MOVIE->count(); $i < $c; $i++ ){

    $html .= '<li>';
    $html .= '<a>
    <img src="https://[url]'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" id="imgThumb" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'" />
    <h1>'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'</h1>
    </a>';
    $html .= ' </li>';

}
$html .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: Silly newbie mistake, I suppose. Thanks! Why not private?

Comment: private function is not valid javascript (yet). private IS a reserved keyword, but it is reserved for future implementation http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are creating new ul for each image. In this loop:

```
     //display image count, encode url/path
for($i = 0, $c = $xml->COM->MOVIE->count(); $i < $c; $i++ ){
    $html .= '<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-listview" data-inset="true">';
    $html .= '<li>';
    $html .= '<a>
    <img  src="https://[url]'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" id="imgThumb" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'" />
    <h1>'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'</h1>
    </a>';
    $html .= ' </li>';
    $html .= '</ul>';
}
```

Create the ul outside the loop, so each li is put inside the same unordered list

Comment: only 33 seconds, but yeah, you were :)